# How to navigate json with nested objects using a dictionary object?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a JSON I would like to navigate using a dictionary object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "entity_id": "weather.home",
    "state": "sunny",
    "attributes": {
        "temperature": 81,
        "temperature_unit": "°F",
        "humidity": 56,
        "pressure": 30.02,
        "pressure_unit": "inHg",
        "wind_bearing": 217.0,
        "wind_speed": 3.11,
        "wind_speed_unit": "mph",
        "visibility_unit": "mi",
        "precipitation_unit": "in",
        "forecast": [
            {
                "condition": "sunny",
                "datetime": "2022-08-25T16:00:00+00:00",
                "wind_bearing": 221.1,
                "temperature": 88,
                "templow": 64,
                "wind_speed": 8.95,
                "precipitation": 0.0
            },
            {
                "condition": "partlycloudy",
                "datetime": "2022-08-26T16:00:00+00:00",
                "wind_bearing": 288.0,
                "temperature": 84,
                "templow": 70,
                "wind_speed": 8.7,
                "precipitation": 0.04
            },
            {
                "condition": "partlycloudy",
                "datetime": "2022-08-27T16:00:00+00:00",
                "wind_bearing": 58.2,
                "temperature": 82,
                "templow": 65,
                "wind_speed": 7.15,
                "precipitation": 0.0
            },
            {
                "condition": "sunny",
                "datetime": "2022-08-28T16:00:00+00:00",
                "wind_bearing": 173.6,
                "temperature": 88,
                "templow": 68,
                "wind_speed": 7.15,
                "precipitation": 0.0
            },
            {
                "condition": "cloudy",
                "datetime": "2022-08-29T16:00:00+00:00",
                "wind_bearing": 211.0,
                "temperature": 92,
                "templow": 75,
                "wind_speed": 7.15,
                "precipitation": 0.18
            }
        ],
        "attribution": "Weather forecast from met.no, delivered by the Norwegian Meteorological Institute.",
        "friendly_name": "Forecast Home"
    },
    "last_changed": "2022-08-24T23:53:34.080002+00:00",
    "last_updated": "2022-08-24T23:53:34.080002+00:00",
    "context": {
        "id": "01GB94D2404DMWGXNV9EHH3Z60",
        "parent_id": null,
        "user_id": null
    }
}
```

**Note: The json has both strings and subobjects as values.**

---

As I have it currently, this is how I am deserializing the object

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

This does work and I can access subobjects like `attributes` but when it comes to accessing the values within that object like `temperature` or `pressure`, I am a bit lost. Here is what my debugger looks like when I get the attributes object

[Attributes object in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eby9p.png)

The sub-values are obviously there but I am not sure how to access them. If possible id like to access them like a dictionary(`atrributes["tempature"]`), I am trying to make it so the user can input a path in the JSON like `attributes.temperature` and get a value back without making an object specifically fit to the json. Is this possible and how would I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using [JsonPath.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPath.Net/0.2.1)? You can try it at https://json-everything.net/json-path. With your example data, the JSON Path `$['attributes']['temperature']` would retrieve the temperature.

Comment: The objects are `JObject` and should function like dictionaries. Or just deserialize it into a proper class with properties, instead of a dictionary.

Comment: You have an array inside of attributes. What data do you want?  From the first, middle or last item of array? Your question is not correct , you have to decide what criteria you need to obtain some data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is recommended that you should have a DTO class to DeserializeObject which is efficient way of getting the property value.

```
enter class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"entity_id\":\"weather.home\",\"state\":\"sunny\",\"attributes\":{\"temperature\":81,\"temperature_unit\":\"\u00B0F\",\"humidity\":56,\"pressure\":30.02,\"pressure_unit\":\"inHg\",\"wind_bearing\":217,\"wind_speed\":3.11,\"wind_speed_unit\":\"mph\",\"visibility_unit\":\"mi\",\"precipitation_unit\":\"in\",\"forecast\":[{\"condition\":\"sunny\",\"datetime\":\"2022-08-25T16:00:00+00:00\",\"wind_bearing\":221.1,\"temperature\":88,\"templow\":64,\"wind_speed\":8.95,\"precipitation\":0},{\"condition\":\"partlycloudy\",\"datetime\":\"2022-08-26T16:00:00+00:00\",\"wind_bearing\":288,\"temperature\":84,\"templow\":70,\"wind_speed\":8.7,\"precipitation\":0.04},{\"condition\":\"partlycloudy\",\"datetime\":\"2022-08-27T16:00:00+00:00\",\"wind_bearing\":58.2,\"temperature\":82,\"templow\":65,\"wind_speed\":7.15,\"precipitation\":0},{\"condition\":\"sunny\",\"datetime\":\"2022-08-28T16:00:00+00:00\",\"wind_bearing\":173.6,\"temperature\":88,\"templow\":68,\"wind_speed\":7.15,\"precipitation\":0},{\"condition\":\"cloudy\",\"datetime\":\"2022-08-29T16:00:00+00:00\",\"wind_bearing\":211,\"temperature\":92,\"templow\":75,\"wind_speed\":7.15,\"precipitation\":0.18}],\"attribution\":\"Weather forecast from met.no, delivered by the Norwegian Meteorological Institute.\",\"friendly_name\":\"Forecast Home\"},\"last_changed\":\"2022-08-24T23:53:34.080002+00:00\",\"last_updated\":\"2022-08-24T23:53:34.080002+00:00\",\"context\":{\"id\":\"01GB94D2404DMWGXNV9EHH3Z60\",\"parent_id\":null,\"user_id\":null}}";
        var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
        JSONClass attributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONClass>(values["attributes"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(attributes.temperature);

    }
}

class JSONClass
{
    public string temperature;

    public string pressure;
}
```